# VBA Excel List of Hyperlinks from activecell containing Array

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink

This is a slightly vague one as I'm really not sure where to start.

I have a dynamic database output that looks something like this:

```
Link1
Link2
Link3,Link4,Link5
Link6
Link7,Link8
```

Where each link represents somewhere else in my spreadsheet. I have VBA code to run through and generate hyperlinks based on cell values, but obviously this doesn't work for a cell which contains multiple links.

My thoughts for getting round this are that I have a user form in the background which becomes visible when the active cell contains ",".

What I need to do is create an array from the Active Cell:

```
arr = Split(ActiveCell.Value, ",")
```

Then have that populate a form which can then be programmed to use the subsequent list as hyperlinks.

I apologise that I haven't done more groundwork on this. I'm struggling to find any existing relevant information.

the key issues here are:

- Which UserForm is best to use? (ComboBox / ListBox ?)
- How to make the form visible based on the contents of the active cell.
- How to get the contents of the Active Cell into the form.
- How to link items in the form to cell references. (A note on this, each 'Linkx' should link to one other cell somewhere in the spreadsheet which contains the exact same value).

Many thanks for any suggestions.
David

**Update:**

I've come up with the following to create the list:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

Cancel = True
Dim arr As Variant
Dim arrin As Variant
Dim ArrLen As Integer
Dim i As Integer

If InStr(1, ActiveCell.Value, ",", vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
    If InStr(1, ActiveCell.Value, "|", vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
        ListBoxDictionary.RemoveAll
        arr = Split(ActiveCell.Value, ",")
        ArrLen = Application.CountA(arr)
        If UserForm1.Visible = True Then
            UserForm1.ListBox1.Clear
        End If
        For i = 0 To ArrLen - 1
            arrin = Split(arr(i), "|")
            UserForm1.ListBox1.AddItem arrin(1) & " - " & Left(arrin(0), InStr(1, arrin(0), "]"))
            ListBoxDictionary(arrin(1) & " - " & Left(arrin(0), InStr(1, arrin(0), "]"))) = arrin(0)
        Next i

        If UserForm1.Visible = False Then
            UserForm1.Show
            UserForm1.Caption = Cells(1, ActiveCell.Column).Value
        End If
    End If
End If


End Sub
```

I now need to determine a way of using 'selected item' to find a matching cell in my workbook. This matching cell is potentially in used cells of Column "D" on all visible worksheets.

Update 2:

For anyone who comes across a similar problem, this is my solution:

```
Global ListBoxDictionary As New Dictionary
Public Sub ListBox1_Click()
    Dim WS_Count As Integer
    Dim WS_No
    Dim Fnd As Integer
    Dim LstItem As String

    WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    Fnd = 0
    LstItem = ListBoxDictionary.Item(ListBox1.Value)

    For WS_No = 1 To WS_Count
        If Fnd <> 1 Then
            If Sheets(WS_No).Name <> "Sheet2" Then
                c = Application.Match(LstItem, Sheets(WS_No).Range("D:D"), 0)
                If IsError(c) Then
                Else
                    Fnd = 1
                    UserForm1.Hide
                    Sheets(WS_No).Activate
                    Sheets(WS_No).Cells(c, "D").Activate
                    UserForm1.ListBox1.Clear
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next WS_No
End Sub
```

the reason for using a dictionary is because I wanted to be able to change the text that shows in the links while preserving the string I needed to search using.

Thanks for the input.
David

Comment: You can add a Forms listbox to the sheet. Use the sheet's `Selection-Change` event to check which cells is selected: if it's one of the "link" cells then split the content and populate the list with the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following to creates the list from the comma delimited string and puts it into the:

(Please note that my list of links has now evolved into:

```
Link1|Description
Link2|Description,Link3|Description
Link4|Description
```

etc.)

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

Cancel = True
Dim arr As Variant
Dim arrin As Variant
Dim ArrLen As Integer
Dim i As Integer

If InStr(1, ActiveCell.Value, ",", vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
    If InStr(1, ActiveCell.Value, "|", vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
        ListBoxDictionary.RemoveAll
        arr = Split(ActiveCell.Value, ",")
        ArrLen = Application.CountA(arr)
        If UserForm1.Visible = True Then
            UserForm1.ListBox1.Clear
        End If
        For i = 0 To ArrLen - 1
            arrin = Split(arr(i), "|")
            UserForm1.ListBox1.AddItem arrin(1) & " - " & Left(arrin(0), InStr(1, arrin(0), "]"))
            ListBoxDictionary(arrin(1) & " - " & Left(arrin(0), InStr(1, arrin(0), "]"))) = arrin(0)
        Next i

        If UserForm1.Visible = False Then
            UserForm1.Show
            UserForm1.Caption = Cells(1, ActiveCell.Column).Value
        End If
    End If
End If


End Sub
```

Along with the above, this is the code used for the listbox itself for the hyperlinking:

```
Global ListBoxDictionary As New Dictionary
Public Sub ListBox1_Click()
    Dim WS_Count As Integer
    Dim WS_No
    Dim Fnd As Integer
    Dim LstItem As String

    WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    Fnd = 0
    LstItem = ListBoxDictionary.Item(ListBox1.Value)

    For WS_No = 1 To WS_Count
        If Fnd <> 1 Then
            If Sheets(WS_No).Name <> "Sheet2" Then
                c = Application.Match(LstItem, Sheets(WS_No).Range("D:D"), 0)
                If IsError(c) Then
                Else
                    Fnd = 1
                    UserForm1.Hide
                    Sheets(WS_No).Activate
                    Sheets(WS_No).Cells(c, "D").Activate
                    UserForm1.ListBox1.Clear
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next WS_No
End Sub
```

the reason for using a dictionary is because I wanted to be able to change the text that shows in the links while preserving the string I needed to search using.

From above, this is the best answer I could come up with.

Thanks for other suggestions.
David.

Answer (score 0):

Add a Forms listbox named "lstLinks" to the sheet and set its "Macro" to `PickedOne`.  It's not clear from your question how you'd actually navigate to the "linked" range.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick Target, False
End Sub


Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim lst As Object, arr, x
Dim lstObj As Object

    Set Target = Target.Cells(1) 'ignore multi-cell selections
    Set lst = Me.Shapes("lstLinks")

    If InStr(Target.Value, ",") > 0 Then
        lst.Visible = True
        lst.Top = Target.Top + Target.RowHeight
        lst.Left = Target.Left
        arr = Split(Target.Value, ",")
        Set lstObj = lst.OLEFormat.Object
        Do While lstObj.ListCount > 0
            lstObj.RemoveItem 1
        Loop
        For x = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
            lstObj.AddItem Trim(arr(x))
        Next x
        Cancel = True
    Else
        lst.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub

Sub PickedOne()
    Dim lst, v
    Set lst = Me.Shapes(Application.Caller)
    v = lst.OLEFormat.Object.List(lst.OLEFormat.Object.ListIndex)
    lst.Visible = False
    ShowItem v
End Sub

Sub ShowItem(v)
    MsgBox "Showing item: " & v
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Tim,
Thanks a lot for your response. I've attempted to test your suggestion but I get the following compile error:
{Invalid Use of Me keyword}

Comment: Code goes in the worksheet code module, not in a regular module.  Right click on the sheet tab and choose "View code"